# Compile time with clang on Linux vs. Mac OSX

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11

I'm working on a cross-platform project using C++11, Boost, Qt and some smaller libraries.

Testing the build on Mac OSX I realized that clang takes only about **66%** of the time compared to clang on Linux Mint 17 on the same machine. Qmake based debug build (-j8) with same settings.

The versions are only slightly different:

- Clang: 3.4
- Boost: 1.55.0
- Qt: 5.3 vs 5.2.1

Switching to libc++ on Linux also made no difference.

Where does this huge difference in compile time come from?
Can I achieve the same speed on Linux?

Comment: How was clang itself compiled?

Comment: I used the one delived with XCode on Mac and the one from the repos on Linux, so nothing fancy from my side. I would guess, they ship optimized versions?

Comment: Are you measuring runs of qmake or runs of clang? How are you measuring?

Comment: Just the overall time, so `time make -j8`

Answer (score 0):

Clang is always built 64-bit AMD64 on OS X, but might be 32-bit x86 depending on your Mint build. 64 vs. 32-bit can definitely have an effect on compiler performance.

Comment: On Linux Mint I get get for `clang --version`: `Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

Comment: @MikeM Use `file /path/to/clang` to see the architecture it is built as, not the target it builds.

Comment: @MikeM You might also try dropping the -j8 from make to eliminate possible differences in process dispatch between the operating systems.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry I didn't see the target... it's `/usr/bin/clang`. 
@eightycc Is there another possibility to compile in parallel if I drop `-j8`?

Comment: @MikeM I think that's exactly the goal: _not_ to compile in parallel. This eliminates possible scheduling differences of the OS, as eightycc said. But there are a lot of other possible reasons related to the OS (for example memory management, if your code is big enough to require a lot of memory). If you're not very lucky, I would think it's going to be very difficult to pinpoint the exact reason.